# Javascript in asp.net mvc3 component called multiple times on a page

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

My project requires to create a component whhich is a cshtml file with a image tag and previous next buttons . The images are loaded dynamically from a webservice when the previous/next buttons are clicked . My "Image" class has four properties required to retrieve the image and my View Model has a list of Image classes . Currently I am converting the model to a json object which is parsed to retreive the image properties on click of previous/next buttons . But my problem is that this component is called multiple times on my main page , so the object is defined multiple times, and the page is confused as to which object to parse and which image tag to load .Please help.

My model class

```
public class ImageRotator
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public string ImageJson { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string imageref { get; set; }
}
```

The controller actions

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
    {
        Image objImage1 = new Image { id = "1", imageref = "abcd" };
        Image objImage2 = new Image { id = "2", imageref = "lmno" };

        ImageRotator objrotator = new ImageRotator();
        List<Image> lstimages = new List<Image>();
        lstimages.Add(objImage1);
        lstimages.Add(objImage2);
        objrotator.images = lstimages;
        objrotator.Title = "quarterly stats";
        objrotator.ImageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objrotator.images);
        return View("Image",objrotator);

    }

    public ActionResult retrieveimage(Image newimage)
    {      


        byte[] image = GetImage(newimage);          

        return Json(new { base64imgage = Convert.ToBase64String(image) }
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Image View

```
     var current=0;
    var obj = <%:Html.ToJson(Model.ImageJson)%>;
      var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
      var image1=obj1[0]
      var url1='<%:Url.Action("retrieveimage","image",new{image="placeholder"}) %>';
  function onClick(btype)  
  {
  if(btype=='P')
  {
      current=current-1;
      image1=obj1[current];
      var imgs=null;

       var displayImage = function (base64Data) {
        var imag =  "data:image/jpg;base64,"
                 + base64Data ;

           $("#resultMessage").attr("src",imag)
         };

       $.ajax({
        url: '/image/retrieveimage',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",            
        data: image1,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // get the result and do some magic with it
           imgs = data;
                displayImage(imgs.base64imgage);

        }
    });
    }
    else if(btype=='P')
    {

    }

     }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <a id="previous" href="javascript:onClick('P');">Previous</a>
   <img id="resultMessage" src="" />
   <a id="next" href="javascript:onClick('N');">Next</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to use this View mutiple times in my Main Page.cshtml

```
 <body>
<div>
Html.Action("GetImage","Image")
 </div>
  <div>
  Html.Action("GetImage","Image").
   </div>
  </body>
```

My problem is that the onClick function appears multiple times when the main page is rendered . How do I ensure that 1. When I click a hyperlink it will know which onClick to call 2. The javascript loads the right image tag.Any help will bbe greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm trying this at home but the actual code will be in razor.

Comment: if you can provide some code we'll be in better position to help

Answer (score 0):

you have not provided any sort of code so my best guess is that the click event is bubbling up and triggering multiple times for each matched element. To prevent the bubbling of the event you can do the following inside the event handler

```
$("#next,#prev").click(function(event){

event.stopImmediatePropagation()

});
```

[.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)